# Netbeans Debugger. How to set a String variable to null?

Tags: debugging, netbeans

anyone know how to set a String variable to null into netbeans debugger?
If I use the variable panel and write null as the variable value it understand the string "null". I tried to completely delete the variable value by pressing canc but it understand the empty string "". How can I set it to null ?

Answer (score 3):

As described at [How can I change the value of a variable while debugging Java code in NetBeans 7.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087305/how-can-i-change-the-value-of-a-variable-while-debugging-java-code-in-netbeans-7), you can use "Evaluate Expression..." under menu Debug option (Ctrl+F9) and execute code snippets in the window while paused at a breakpoint. For example, type

> myStringVariable = null;

then press Ctrl+Enter or click on the green button in the lower right corner of the window to execute that code.